# jquery index first-line children

Tags: jquery, children

I want to get the n-th first level child of a parent. For example, when I have dom like this:

```
<div id='myDiv'>
    <p>first paragraph</p>
    <p>second paragraph<span>something here</span></p>
    <p>third paragraph</p>
</div>
```

and use eq(), like here:

```
alert($('#myDiv').children().eq(2).html());
```

I get 'something here', but 'third paragraph' is what I need, because 'something here' is the second generation child of myDiv and should not be taken into account. I know I would use '>' selector, but I have to write a versatile script, which could work not only with 'p' children, but also 'a', 'li', 'whatever'. Hope you understand what I mean. Thanks in advance for help

**UPDATE**

You are right - there is nothing wrong with my js code. But, as you suggested, I have looked into my html, and saw something strange happening there. I have:

```
    <div>
<div><span>Option1</span> <span>Option2</span> <span>Option3</span> <span>Option4</span></div>
<div><p>Container1</p> <p><div>abc</div></p> <p>Container3</p> <p>Container4</p></div>
</div>
```

and what I see in elements field in browser:

```
<div>
<div><span>Option1</span> <span>Option2</span> <span>Option3</span> <span>Option4</span></div>
<div><p>Container1</p> <p></p><div>abc</div><p></p> <p>Container3</p> <p>Container4</p></div>
</div>
```

Why the paragraph is being closed before the div, and opened again after?

Comment: Your code is correct: http://jsfiddle.net/NtKGf/. `.children` is the same as using the child selector (`>`). If it doesn't work for you, you have an error in your HTML, making the `span` element a child of the `div`. The child selector (and `.children()`) do exactly what their names suggests: They select the children of an element. The `span` element is not a child of the div element, it is a *descendant*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why the paragraph is being closed before the div, and opened again after?

Because a paragraph cannot contain a div element (to be more precise, I think a paragraph cannot contain a block element).  The browser corrects your invalid(!) markup by closing the paragraph before the div.

Comment: Did not know about it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
alert(
    $($('#myDiv > *')[2]).html()
);
```

Comment: And what's wrong with the OP's code? Instead of writing `$($(...)[2])`, use `.eq`: `$(...).eq(2)`.

Comment: OP says he doesn't want to use the `>` selector.

Comment: @Charlie: After rereading the question, I think the OP just didn't know about the universal selector (`*`) and hence thought he cannot use it.

Comment: Felix Kling: To be honest, I did not test the OP's code :) But you are right, his code should work

Comment: Thank you Pascal for your answer. My code should work. I have updated my question